# Bind two wide frames into panel in R

Tags: r, panel, reshape

I've got two data frames that each correspond to a different time period that I would like to bind together. The have different variable names for the same variable, but the frames are ordered such that the 2nd column in the first frame corresponds to the 2nd column in the second frame, etc. For example:

```
set.seed(123)
f1 <- data.frame(name = c("a", "b", "c"), t = c(1,1,1), x1 = sample(0:10,3), x2 =  sample(0:10,3))
f2 <- data.frame(name = c("a", "b", "c"),  t = c(2,2,2), y1 = sample(0:10,3), y2 =  sample(0:10,3))
```

I would like to bind these on the name variable such that it produces a dataset like:

```
  name t v1 v2
1    a 1  3  9
2    a 2  5  5
3    b 1  7 10
4    b 2  8  9
5    c 1 10  0
6    c 2  4  4
```

Any recommendations on how to reshape the frame without having to account for variable names like this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data.table` package has a `rbind` method for that which has the `use.names` argument which can be set to `FALSE` in order to ignore different column names.

```
library(data.table) # V 1.9.6+
rbind(setDT(f1), setDT(f2), use.names = FALSE)[order(name)]
#    name t x1 x2
# 1:    a 1  3  9
# 2:    a 2  5  5
# 3:    b 1  7 10
# 4:    b 2  8  9
# 5:    c 1 10  0
# 6:    c 2  4  4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
colnames(f1) <- colnames(f2)
x <- rbind(f2, f1)     
x <- x[order(x$name, x$t),]
> x
name t y1 y2
4    a 1  3  9
1    a 2  5  5
5    b 1  7 10
2    b 2  8  9
6    c 1 10  0
3    c 2  4  4
```